# Paste data from group table into a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need a new table from the summary table once the submit button is clicked.
[image: Main Table]

I am trying to copy the first row and no idea how to go to the new column as required. The new data should be pasted to the empty column.

The below code is working for rows.

```vb
Sub data_input2()
    
    ws_output = "Sheet3"
    
    next_row = Sheets(ws_output).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
    Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 1).Value = Range("B1").Value
    Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 2).Value = Range("B2").Value
    Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 3).Value = Range("B3").Value
    Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 4).Value = Range("A8").Value
    Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 5).Value = Range("B8").Value
    Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 6).Value = Range("C5").Value
    Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 7).Value = Range("C6").Value
    Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 8).Value = Range("C7").Value
    Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 9).Value = Range("C8").Value
    
End Sub
```

It should look like this after clicking the submit.
[image: Data to look like]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post code as image as it is very hard to help you then. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question.

Comment: @Ike, I have changed the code accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust as necessary...

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range, cOut As Range
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("Input")  'has your original table
    
    Set cOut = Worksheets("Output").Range("A2") 'start of reformatted data
    'start at next empty row on sheet
    'Set cOut = Worksheets("Output").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    'loop through the data values
    For Each c In ws.Range("C8:J11").Cells
        cOut.Resize(1, 9).Value = Array(ws.Range("B1").Value, ws.Range("B2").Value, _
                        ws.Range("B3").Value, MergeValue(c.EntireRow.Cells(1)), _
                        c.EntireRow.Cells(2).Value, MergeValue(c.EntireColumn.Cells(5)), _
                        MergeValue(c.EntireColumn.Cells(6)), _
                        MergeValue(c.EntireColumn.Cells(7)), c.Value)
        Set cOut = cOut.Offset(1) 'next row down
    Next c
    
    
End Sub

'return the value from a (maybe merged) cell
Function MergeValue(c As Range)
    MergeValue = c.MergeArea(1).Value
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Instead of always start to paste the data from A2, Can we paste these details from the next empty row. Thanks

Comment: See added line above